# How to set font and theme for GTK+2 programs from the command-line on Linux?

Tags: fonts, theme, gtk2

I know how to set font for GTK+3 programs from the command-line, namely by editing the right-hand side (RHS) of ~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini's font line:

```
gtk-font-name=Font Awesome 5 Free Regular
```

likewise to set the GTK+ 3 font I'd edit the RHS of:

```
gtk-theme-name=Qogir-win-light
```

(these lines are taken from my settings.ini file) but I do not know how to do so for GTK+ 2 programs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting [the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GTK+#Configuration):

> To manually change the GTK+ theme, icons, font and font size, add the following to the configuration files, for example:

```
~/.gtkrc-2.0

gtk-icon-theme-name = "Adwaita"
gtk-theme-name = "Adwaita"
gtk-font-name = "DejaVu Sans 11"
```